# Disaply products from category

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a working script responsible for displaying woocommerce products on my page which goes something like this:

```
<?php
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 99, 'post_type' => 'product');
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>
<div class="list-of-products">
     <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
     <div class="listed-product">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <h4>
               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
               </a>
          </h4>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          <a class="listed-product-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More</a>
     </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php else:  ?>
     <div>
          <?php _e( 'No products' ); ?>
     </div>
     <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

It works fine, but now I wanted to use the same script on another page to only show products from certain category, so I changed the `$params` line to something like this

```
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 99, 'post_type' => 'product', 'category_name' => 'category-name');
```

Where in place of `category-name` is actuall name of the category I want to display. The problem is it doesn't display any products, instead showing the `No products` text I set up in case of having 0 products. I tried the same with `'cat' => 43` which is suppoused to be the category id but again no results. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using categories (and not a custom taxonomy) then your     `category-name`    needs to be the slug, not the actual name.

If, however, you are using a custom taxononomy (and you'll know if you are) then you should use

```
 'name-of-your-custom-tax' => 'slug'
```

You can also see the below links for details.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters